# Is there any way to find compile options used in package installation from source?

Tags: linux, package, configure, installation

I built this package from source a while back and I need to know the options I used.

I still have the directory I ran the `./configure` on and it's untouched.

Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to search for `config.log` in the directory you ran `configure` in.

The chances are good you'll find the parameters passed to `./configure` in there.